# How to test null hypothesis with partly confounded multinomial dependent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, multinomial-distribution

I have independent sample data consisting of 12 levels, where the dependent variable is multinomial with three possible outcomes corresponding to Strategy 1, Strategy 2, and Strategy 3. Each level is associated with a numeric value ranging from -10 to 10. I want to test the hypothesis that these numeric values predict which strategy is applied the most. However, Strategy 2 and Strategy 3 are confounded in levels 1-6, making it impossible to determine which strategy was used in those cases (because they yield the same outcome). So far, I have attempted to conduct three separate logistic regression analyses, one for each strategy, using the numeric values as continuous predictors. But I wonder if there is a better approach to test this hypothesis? Preferably using a single test.

| Strategy (DV) | Level 1 | Level 2 | Level 3 | Level 4 | Level 5 | Level 6 | Level 7 | Level 8 | Level 9 | Level 10 | Level 11 | Level 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Strategy 1 | 10 | 8 | 4 | -10 | -8 | -4 | -4 | -8 | -10 | 4 | 8 | 10 |
| Strategy 2 | 9 | 5 | -3 | -9 | -5 | 3 | 3 | -5 | -9 | -3 | 5 | 9 |
| Strategy 3 | 9 | 5 | -3 | -9 | -5 | 3 | -3 | 5 | 9 | 3 | -5 | -9 |

Thankful for help!